# Ctrl +Shift + Enter not working with Visual Studio 2013 power productivity tools

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have two computers at home. Both have Visual Studio 2013 with power productivity tools extension. The only difference is one computer has windows 7 while another is running windows 8.1.

Both are running same edition of visual studio and latest updates are installed. But on windows 8.1 machine pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> does not put semicolon while with windows 7 it's working fine.

Can anyone please tell me is that OS specific problem or there is a bug in power productivity tools for visual studio 2013.

reference: http://abhijitjana.net/2010/07/21/use-shiftenter-to-add-automatically-at-end-of-the-line-visual-studio-2010-productivity-power-tool/ - This link is for visual studio 2010 but now visual studio 2013 got same functionality with Ctrl + Shift + Enter.

Comment: Occam's razor demands the simple explanation for this problem.  Tends to be the correct one, the add-in simply is not enabled on your Win8 machine.  Pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter now performs the normal Edit.LineOpenBelow operation.  Which looks a *lot* like the add-in's operation, minus the semi-colon.

Comment: Do you have ReSharper installed?

Comment: @HansPassant All other features are working fine for power productivity tools. Only this one is not working in windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Just tested it on mine (VS2013 w/Power Tools) in a C# file on windows 8.1 and it worked.

My recommendation is that you verify that the mapping (`Edit.LineOpenBelow`) is mapped to the keystroke.

Do you have other tools which may have taken the mapping such as Resharper?

If the mapping is there and appears to be assigned, try to change the mapping and see if it it works or fails. The mapping can be found in the keyboard options here:

[image]

Comment: Does it put semicolon at the end of line?. I don't have resharper!

Comment: @JalpeshVadgama yes it does; unless a semi colon is there already.

Comment: @JalpeshVadgama I have seen installs/updates to other products, such as an Azure install cause Visual Studio Problems, due to installing something which is used by VS but has become out of sync with the original. Try to do a `repair` to Visual Studio using the latest VS update to see if it resolves this.

Comment: I have already done repair and I have latest update there. But still not working

Comment: @JalpeshVadgama In looking at the power tools, it no longer lists this feature as one it installs; hence its baked into VS. You don't by chance have 2010 and 2013 on your system? I wonder if there is some bizarre dll share issue.

Comment: Nope i don't have visual studio 2010 there in any of machine. I have only visual studio 2013 on both machine.

Comment: As i said earlier I don't have resharper!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently in Windows 8 (and Windows 8.1) a special shortcut was added to run a task without showing the UAC notification to grant administrator privileges when running a specific application.

Surprisingly the shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Source: http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/command-prompt-administrator-shortcut/

So the question is how to disable it and if it will solve your issue:

> You can disable the sequence Ctrl + Shift in Windows 8.
>
> 1. In "Control Panel" | "Clock, Language and Region" | "Language" click "Advanced Settings" in the left pane.
> 2. In "Advanced settings" click "Change Language bar hot keys"
> 3. In "Text Services and Input Languages" click "Change Key Sequence" button and disable the the key sequence by selecting the "Not
>      Assigned" radio buttons.

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/604790/how-to-disable-ctrlshift-keyboard-layout-switch-in-windows-8

Or you can try to disable the UAC:

> Open up the Start screen, search for UAC, and you should see an option
>   for User Account Control settings. If you don’t, you’ll need to change
>   to search through your Settings first, but then you should see it.
>   And then you can drag the slider all the way to the bottom, the same
>   as for the other versions of Windows.

Source: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-user-account-control-uac-the-easy-way-on-windows-vista/

You can also try using SharpKeys to redefine the specific keyboard sequence:

Download link: http://www.randyrants.com/2011/12/sharpkeys_35/

Guide: http://www.askvg.com/customize-any-key-in-your-keyboard-using-sharpkeys/

Now, after doing it, please try the hotkey in VS2013.

Let me know if that support your issue,